# Evaluate class with a pseudo-class selector in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm looking for a solution to get an element with a pseudo-class of visited (`a:visited`).

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't find any information on that. Is this even possible with puppeteer?

Comment: You mean [like this](https://medium.com/how-tos-for-coders/https-medium-com-kaushalshah1307-get-pseudo-elements-using-javascript-b64c88a96c46)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `:visited` pseudo-class due to privacy protection. [See also](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#privacy).